# Typescript React How to Prepare Component to Expect Different Types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, api

I'm fetching some data from an API that looks like this:

```
features: [
  {
    featureId: '1',
    featureName: 'Damage feature 1',
    featureType: 'STRING',
  },
  {
    featureId: '2',
    featureName: 'Damage feature 2',
    featureType: 'DATETIME',
  },
  {
    featureId: '3',
    featureName: 'Damage feature 3',
    featureType: 'INTEGER',
  },
],
```

They are of different types, as you can see, they can be an integer, a string, a datetime, many different kinds, and I'm mapping them in a component like this:

```
interface CategoryFeatureProps {
  feature: string;
}

export const CategoryFeature = ({ feature }: CategoryFeatureProps) => {
  return (
    <p>{feature}</p>
  );
};
```

I'd like to know the correct way in Typescript to prepare the component to expect these different types in the interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to update your `CategoryFeatureProps` to the following based on what you've currently got:

```
interface CategoryFeatureProps {
  feature: {
    featureId: string;
    featureName: string;
    featureType: string | number | Date;
  }
}
```

If you really wanted to break it up a bit more you could also do this:

```
type FeatureType = string | number | Date;

interface Feature {
  featureId: string;
  featureName: string;
  featureType: FeatureType;
}

interface CategoryFeatureProps {
  feature: Feature;
}
```

**Additional Note:**

```
export const CategoryFeature = ({ feature }: CategoryFeatureProps) => {
  return (
    <p>{feature}</p>
  );
}
```

This won't work because you can't render an object in React like this, rather just do something like this for now to test it all out:

```
export const CategoryFeature = ({ feature }: CategoryFeatureProps) => {
  return (
    <p>{JSON.stringify(feature)}</p>
  );
}
```

Now you'll safely render a string version of the object.

Comment: That's great! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome, happy coding!